# Example of schwarz lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Show that if $f$ is analytic such that $|f(z)|<1$ and $f(0)=c$ for $|z|<1$. Then 
                                 $|f(z)-c|≤\frac{|z|(1-|c|^2)}{(1-|c||z|)}$

I have tried to solve this problem, however I got hooked at the denominator. I will be glad if the solution can be provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a fractional linear transformation reduces this to the case $c=0$.

Comment: You mean $\phi(z) = \frac{z-c}{1-\overline{c}z}$ ? The Schwarz lemma gives $|\phi(f(z))| < |z|$ and $|f(z)-c| < |z| |1-\overline{c}f(z)|$

Comment: Yes $ϕ(z)=\frac{z−c}{1−\bar{c}z}$. I couldn't still prove it